# The "if, else if, and else" condition on my code is being read incorrectly

Tags: javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load2() {
            var objDate2 = new Date();
            var hour = objDate2.getHours()
            var minute = objDate2.getMinutes()
            if (hour === 12 | 24 && minute < 24 && minute >= 12){
                document.getElementById("Hour").style.animation = "rotate1 43200s linear 0s infinite normal";
            }
            else if (hour === 12 | 24 && minute < 36 && minute >= 24){
                document.getElementById("Hour").style.animation = "rotate2 43200s linear 0s infinite normal";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("Hour").style.animation = "rotate 43200s linear 0s infinite normal";
            }
        }
</script>
```

problem is the statement hour === 12 | 24 && minute < 36 && minute >= 24 being read incorrectly.

Comment: `12 | 24` missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used `|` instead of `||` . `||` is the [or operator](http://addyosmani.com/blog/exploring-javascripts-logical-or-operator/) and `|` is the [bitwise or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR)

So here is the edited code:

```
function load2() {
        var objDate2 = new Date();
        var hour = objDate2.getHours()
        var minute = objDate2.getMinutes()
        if (hour === 12 || 24 && minute < 24 && minute >= 12){
            document.getElementById("Hour").style.animation = "rotate1 43200s linear 0s infinite normal";
        }
        else if (hour === 12 || 24 && minute < 36 && minute >= 24){
            document.getElementById("Hour").style.animation = "rotate2 43200s linear 0s infinite normal";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("Hour").style.animation = "rotate 43200s linear 0s infinite normal";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`|` is a bitwise operator use `||` for logical OR operation.

12 | 24 = 28 which does not make sense in your code.

Replace

```
if (hour === 12 | 24 && minute < 24 && minute >= 12){
```

with

```
if ((hour === 12 || hour === 24) && minute < 24 && minute >= 12){
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the bitwise operator meaning its comparing hour to (12 | 24). use || for logical compare.